Python pymodbus can't read Mitsubishi Parameters
I have to read 1 parameter from my Mitsubishi Melservo J4, more specifically it is a MR-J4-40A-RJ.
I can actually read parameters from a program called QModMaster.
The settings for the connection are these:
Settings image 1
Settings image 2
Summarized are:

Modbus mode: RTU
Slave addr: 1
Scan rate: 1000 ms
Function code: Read Holding Registers (0x03)
Start Address: 2103 Hex
Nuber of registers: 2
Serial device: COM
Serial port: 7
Baud: 115200
Data Bits: 8
Stop Bits: 2
Parity: None
RTS: Enable

My python code is this, and is not working because it goes in timeout before getting some data:
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException

# Create Modbus client instance
client = ModbusClient(
    method='rtu',
    port='COM7',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity='N',
    stopbits=2,
    bytesize=8,
    timeout=1,
    rtscts=True
)

# Connect to the serial port
connection = client.connect()
if connection:
    print("Connected to the Modbus server")
else:
    print("Failed to connect to the Modbus server")

# Register address and number of registers to read
register_address = 0x2103  # 2103h in hexadecimal
num_registers = 2

# Reading the registers
try:
    response = client.read_holding_registers(register_address, num_registers, unit=1)
    if not isinstance(response, ModbusIOException):
        # Decode the response
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(response.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
        parameter_value = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
        print(f"Parameter PC03 value: {parameter_value}")
    else:
        print(f"Error reading registers: {response}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception: {e}")

# Close the client
client.close()

And i get this error from the "response":
Error reading registers: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)
From the documentation this is the 2103h parameter:
Parameter Image
I hope i was clear, ask any question i will give further info.
Thanks.
I tried my python code, i was expecting at least some byte, but i'm getting 0 bytes.

Oh i got it, hope this will help somebody that need to communicate via serial to some device like mine.
The problem was that i set this wrong:
response = client.read_holding_registers(register_address, num_registers, unit=1)

Mean while it should be:
response = client.read_holding_registers(start_address, count, slave=1)

So the problem was that you have to set "slave" and not "unit"
Hope this will help somebody with a sample code.
